# Accessing an array in a standard class object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I need to access the array coordinates in this:

```
object stdClass Object ( 
    [type] => Point 
    [coordinates] => Array ( 
        [0] => 53.64203491 
        [1] => -8.52337036 
    ) 
)
```

But no matter what I try I can't get it. Any ideas? I am using PHP.

Comment: What's the name of the variable you're printing/dumping here?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: `$stdObject->coordinates[0]` and `$stdObject->coordinates[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the variable is $data, then you can access the the coordinates array as follows:-

$coordinatesArr = $data->coordinates;

I think this should work. If it does not, please share the peice of code you are using.